# Float image to the left in CSS

Tags: css, image, css-float

I'm trying to do something like:

```
--------------------------------------------
| --------- text text text text text text  |
| | image | text text text text text text  |
| |       | text text text text text text  |
| |       | text text text text text text  |
| --------- text text text text text text  |
| text text text text text text text text  |
| text text text text text text text text  |
--------------------------------------------
```

The markup should be right:

```
<div>
    <img src='myimage.jpg' style='float:left;'>
    tex text text ..
</div>
```

The problem is - if there's only a few text, the image will "float out" from the container div, which looks like this:

```
--------------------------------------------
| --------- text text text text text text  |
| | image | text text text text text text  |
|_|       |________________________________|
  |       |
  ---------
```

How can I fix this? the only solution to me seems setting the div container's min-height.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
div {
    overflow: hidden;  /* except IE6 */
    display: inline-block; /* IE6 */
}
div {
    display: block; /* IE6 */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

add an empty element at the end of the `div` element with `style="clear:both;`, just like this:

```
<div>
    <img src='myimage.jpg' style='float:left;'>
    tex text text ..
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a valid solution as well, though it complicates the markup. I have run into cases where the overflow trick doesn't suit my needs, and a `div` with `clear: both` is necessary.

Comment: Very helpful answer indeed. Except **don't** add the CSS code `clear:both;` inline in your HTML code. As usual, do it in your CSS file. In my case, I added the clearing `<div>` just before `</main>`, like so: <div class="clearboth"></div>. And in my CSS file I have `.clearboth {clear: both;}`.

Comment: On second thought, given that you don't want to be dependent on being able to change the HTML code, it might be worth considering `clearfix`: [https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/). Unfortunately I don't have the time to experiment with it right now.

Comment: Actually, I solved **without** making _any_ changes to the HTML code. The trick was to add `overflow: auto;` to the **parent** of the "overflowing" `<div>` tag (in my case `<aside>`). Like so, `main {overflow:auto;}`. (Where `<main>` in my case is the parent tag.)

Answer (score 1):

<div style="overflow:auto"> </div>